# how to convert Ruby application 1.8.7 to 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi I have one application in ruby but in that application developed in ruby 1.8.7, now  I am using ruby 1.9.2 any possibility to change my application 1.8.2 to 1.9.2 or 1.9.3

Comment: Sure that is possible. What have you done already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this [tutorial](http://nerds.airbnb.com/upgrading-from-ree-187-to-ruby-193) is helpful to start working on upgrading your application to Ruby-1.9.3

He explained nicely how to upgrade from Ruby-1.8.7 to Ruby-1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Given that your rails app is using day-to-day ruby functions, upgrading to ruby 1.9 should not be an issue, however read this [major changes note](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/NEWS), from ruby 1.8 to 1.9.x and see if you are using any methods that are mentioned there. But practically in most cases your rails app should run without any modifications.

And when you are installing ruby1.9.x use [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io/) , to have your both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9 versions side-by-side.

and if you have a good test suite, this should not be a problem at all :)

best of luck